# How to increment the `k` here?

Tags: lua

I was trying to increment the `k` in a for loop like this:

```
t = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

for k = 1, #t do
    if k == 1 then 
        print(t[1])
    else
        print(t[k], t[k + 1], t[k + 2])
        k = k + 2
    end 
end
```

But it's not working! How to increment this `k` in `else` block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter variable used in a `for`-loop won't propagate between iterations. Consider

```
for i=1, 3 do
    print(i)
end
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
```

Now consider

```
for i=1, 3 do 
    print(i)
    i = i+1 
    print(i, '\n')
end
-- 1
-- 2
--
-- 2
-- 3
--
-- 3
-- 4
```

Note that there is no change in the leading values (1, 2, 3).

The solution is to convert the `for`-loop into a `while`-loop, giving more freedom and control over the variable.

```
k = 1
while k < #t do
    if k == 1 then
        print(t[1])
    else
        print(t[k], t[k+1], t[k+2])
        k = k + 2
    end
    k = k + 1
end
-- 1
-- 2    3   4
-- 5    6   7
-- 8    9   10
```

Comment: Nice illustration. Is there any other language where we can't change the `counter` in a `for` loop?

Comment: @Emon Python comes to mind, using something like `for i in range(3): ...` You can still change the value, like Lua, only it won't modify the value on the next iteration.

Comment: @Emon It would be better to look at it the other way around: Which languages have for loops that are defined as equivalent to while loops (especially those where you actually write the code to do the incrementing or whatever)?

Comment: @TomBlodget, burrying `fortran` and `cobol`, we can say ... on `pascal` type `begin … end` we can't do it BUT on `C` type `{...}` we can, right?